# How to auto create Leads from a giant list per day?

Tags: leads

I have a giant spreadsheet which is a list of 1,000+ potential clients. I would like to produce 10 new Leads from this per day to be used by our sales team. Is there a way to do this automatically ? All I can think of is to peel off 10 per day and import them.

Could Informatica be beneficial with this ? I know I could set up tasks to run an upsert daily, but I don't know how I would peel off only 10 every day.

I'm also wondering if maybe I could just import the entire list all at once into an object I create and then just have some kind of scheduled job run on it. Somehow that scheduled act would peel off 10 a day and create a Lead record for each...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that and you have already mentioned the recommended approaches in your question:

1. Use an ETL tool, such as Informatica or PentaHo, to pick first 10 rows from the .csv sheet and insert them to Salesforce. Update the sheet or create a new sheet with remaining rows. I am not sure about Informatica, but PentaHo has inbuilt features for supporting Salesforce integration.
2. Setup a staging object in Salesforce and insert all the records in this object. Create a scheduler job to convert any 10 rows and update their status to not to be picked in next job or delete them. You also could use process builders to create a new lead record and keep the minimal code for maintenance.